# How to replicate this form with exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I'm wondering how can I achieve something like that "Browse Listing" block (on the right) with exposed filters - http://demo.rlisting.com/rlisting/result
Should I create Content type for each Property type and add Listing type as a vocabulary or to use only one content type for all properties and then add property and listing types as vocabulary or as text fields with select list?
And more importantly how Min & Max range could be created?

using drupal 7.14, views 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view, with display page and add some exposed filters.
Then you have to enable the function "Expose form in block", or something like this, that creates a block with your exposed filters.

Comment: I know the basics of exposed filters. I was looking for something advanced and therefore to answer my question - how the example I gave can be replicated and how Min and Max range works with exposed filters.